# why External link as query string in link?

Tags: php, html, drupal

```
http://example.com/links?http://www.domain.com/complete...
```

I have seen this kind of link, which contains external link as query string. What is the benefit of doing this.. and how to do this?

Comment: It's usually for tracking which links the user has clicked.

Comment: Or, as the original posting was showing, the benefit was immedieately redirecting to the link passed.

Answer (score 0):

If example.com were an advertising company they could track that you had clicked the link to domain.com and record it. You hit their URL to record the click and it then forwards you on to the domain in the query string.